# Where is endl manipulator defined

Tags: c++, gcc, endl

We know that `endl` is manipulator and internally it put `'\n'` to buffer and then flush up the buffer. Where is `endl` defined? What is `endl`, is it macro or function or variable or class or object? How can I define my own `endl` manipulator?

```
cout << "hello" << endl ; /*what is endl and  where it is defined */
```

Comment: The `std::endl` manipulator is defined in `<ostream>` header.

Comment: in definition of endl, it seems like it is function then why we are not passing any argument when we use it with cout                                             template< class CharT, class Traits >
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& endl( std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os );

Comment: I attempted to clarify the question, I think there is a good question here and it has attracted an excellent answer from Yakk.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`std::endl` is a function template of signature:

```
template<class CharT, class Traits>
std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& endl(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&);
```

The `std::basic_ostream::operator<<` overload `std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>>::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&))` accepts a function of a certain signature.

When you do `std::cout << std::endl`, overload resolution is done on `std::endl`, which determines the proper template types for `std::endl` and instantiates a function.  This then decays into a pointer, and is passed to `operator<<`.

`std::basic_ostream::operator<<` then calls the function on the ostream in question, and returns the return value.  Something like:

```
template<class CharT, class Traits>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>&
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>::operator<<(
  std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&)
) {
  return func(*this);
}
```

But the exact implementation is up to the compiler library writer<sup>1</sup>.

`std::endl` causes a newline to be printed, and then tells the ostream to flush itself.  You can emulate doing `std::cout << std::endl;` via these two lines of code:

```
std::cout.put(std::cout.widen('\n'));
std::cout.flush();
```

How exactly `std::endl` is implemented is up to the compiler, but the above is a decent approximation of how you might write it (naturally on a generic stream).

You are guaranteed to have access to `std::endl` if you `#include <ostream>`.  You may have access to it if you include any other header file from the `std` library.  What file exactly defines it is again up to the implementation.

`std::endl` is known as an "io manipulator".  This technique is intended to allow functions that manipulate the io stream's state to be set up "inline" with output commands by chaining `<<` calls together.

To create your own, if you want it to work with a single type of ostream, simply create a function that takes that kind of `ostream` by reference, and returns it by reference.  It is now an io manipulator.

If you want to handle a set of streams, create a template like:

```
template<class CharT, class Traits>
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& bob(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os)
{
  return os << os.widen('b') << os.widen('o') << os.widen('b');
}
```

which is now an io manipulator that prints `"bob"`.  It can do whatever you want to the `basic_ostream` in question.

An alternative plan is this:

```
struct bob_t {
  template<class OS>
  OS& operator()(OS& os)const {
    return os << os.widen('b') << os.widen('o') << os.widen('b');
  }
  template<class OS>
  operator OS&(*)(OS&)() const {
    return [](OS& os)->OS&{ return bob_t{}(os); };
  }
};
static const bob_t bob;
```

where `bob` is now an object that can be used as an io manipulator.

---

<sup>1</sup> This `<<` overload is a function of type `A->(A->A)->A`.  Basically, instead of passing X to f, we pass X and f to `<<`, which then does `f(X)`.  Pure syntactic sugar.

The fact that `std::endl` is a template means that perfect forwarding it is a bit of a pain due to this technique.  I end up defining stateless function `endl_t` types, with an `operator basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&(*)(basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>&)()const` overload, so I can pass the overload set through perfect forwarding proxies sometimes.

Then we can pass the entire overload set of `f:(A->A)` to `<<`, and have the "next layer down" resolve the overload.

Comment: This is a completely awesome answer, not sure why this is not the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl says:

> Defined in header `<ostream>`

```
template< class CharT, class Traits >
std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& endl( std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& os );
```

> if i want to code my own endl manipulator what code i will have to write?

If you want to create it only for `std::ostream` just create a function that accepts reference to `std::ostream` and returns one. If you want to make it generic you can make it templatized, like `std::endl`.

Comment: so it seems like it is function and if it is then why we are not passing any argument to it?

Comment: @NiravsinhParmar becase it is done inside overloaded `operator<<` that accepts a function of certain signature.